# How to use properties in C#

Tags: c#, properties

The error I receive when I create an Object of `Class1` and attempt to run this property using Main is:

> "Error    1   Non-invocable member 'ConsoleApplication1.Class1.X_ValueProperty' cannot be used like a method. C:\Users\Qosmio\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs 14  15  ConsoleApplication1"

I understand this error perfectly well. I.E, you can't run a property as if it's a method, but it seems the presenter of the [video I learned this from](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iGR425gMKeA) is able to do so. *(Around the 1:20 mark.)*

In the Main method, it seems he calls the object, then the property, and inputs a value where as I get the error.

Can anyone identify what I'm doing wrong?

```
class Class1
{
    int x;

    public int X_ValueProperty
    {
        set {
            if (value <= 0)
            {
                throw new Exception("Value cannot be zero or less than zero.");
            }
            this.x = value;
            }
        get 
        {
            return this.x;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is where the error comes in:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Class1 z= new Class1();

        //Error--> z.X_ValueProperty();


    }   
}
```

Comment: Show us the line of code that causes the error.

Comment: I'm going to guess you are doing something like `var p = myClass1.X_ValueProperty();` instead of `var p = myClass1.X_ValueProperty;`

Comment: so yes, Blorgbeard is right!

Comment: Yeah. Thx for the help guys. Simple error but it was very frustrating.  :) Just a formatting issue on the account of me being a noob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be invoking the property something like this:-

```
Class1 cls = new Class1();
cls.X_ValueProperty();
```

Please notice its a property and not a method, you can set or get the value of a property of a class. Please read about [Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) properly first.

You can set\get values like this:-

```
cls.X_ValueProperty = 25;
int x = cls.X_ValueProperty;
```

Comment: Thx. That did it. I was using ( value); instead of = value;.